# Azure Default Reader vs Built-in Monitoring Reader

Tags: azure, security, cloud, azure-web-roles, azure-rbac

I am trying to setup narrow down the best possible role for monitoring data from security perspective. My needs are slightly different so I don't want to use the Security Reader role (mainly because security reader only has access to the security center items and basic resource and resource group queries). So after reading more I stumbled upon Monitoring Reader role and just Reader role. I went through the permissions mentioned in the JSON. However I am not sure if all the differences are covered in the JSON.

For instance when we talk about "Monitoring Reader"

```
{
  "assignableScopes": [
    "/"
  ],
  "description": "Can read all monitoring data.",
  "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/43d0d8ad-25c7-4714-9337-8ba259a9fe05",
  "name": "43d0d8ad-25c7-4714-9337-8ba259a9fe05",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "actions": [
        "*/read",
        "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/search/action",
        "Microsoft.Support/*"
      ],
      "notActions": [],
      "dataActions": [],
      "notDataActions": []
    }
  ],
  "roleName": "Monitoring Reader",
  "roleType": "BuiltInRole",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions"
}
```

The privileges are basically the same expect that I can query the logs. Compared to the Reader role which is

```
{
  "assignableScopes": [
    "/"
  ],
  "description": "Lets you view everything, but not make any changes.",
  "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7",
  "name": "acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "actions": [
        "*/read"
      ],
      "notActions": [],
      "dataActions": [],
      "notDataActions": []
    }
  ],
  "roleName": "Reader",
  "roleType": "BuiltInRole",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions"
}
```

Now from a logical standpoint if both the users are able to execute `*/read` doesn't Reader role automatically qualify to query the logs? If not, how is it different? Also which role is superior in terms of access to readable data?

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader

PS : I do know about custom roles but want to understand built-in roles better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now from a logical standpoint if both the users are able to execute */read doesn't Reader role automatically qualify to query the logs?

They are both able to execute `*/read`, but `Reader` cannot query the logs.

> If not, how is it different?

The difference is `Monitoring Reader` can execute the `Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/search/action` and `Microsoft.Support/*` actions.

> Also which role is superior in terms of access to readable data?

From the `actions` scope of the role definition, obviously the `Monitoring Reader`  is superior in terms of access to readable data.